# Firestore batch splitting

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I'm just wondering, wouldn't it be easier for us to get a method of splitting a batch into 500 ops directly within the SDK ?

I'm thinking it would be a lot easier to split it after all operations are accounted for, rather than upfront, when you have no clue how many operations will there be in total.

The SDK itself will easily pick up on sentinels (placeholders) which account for additional writes and so on.

Unless, I am missing something and there is already such a method?
I'm wondering because I'm tired of splitting uneven chunks, doing more requests than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method.  If you have a feature request for Firebase SDKs, please [file it here](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature).